# Spring data with custom query - like, between, like and order by

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, spring-data, jhipster

how I can pass this string "sql" for a Spring Data @Query?

My Class Resources:

```
public void findMessage(String startDate, String endDate, String id, String values, String fieldName, String sort){

      String sql = "SELECT e FROM message e WHERE (e.create_at BETWEEN '"+ 
                   startDate+ "' AND "+"'"+ endDate +"') AND (e.id = '"+id+"') 
                   AND (e.category LIKE '%"+values+"%') ORDER BY 
                   e."+fieldName+" "+sortParam;
}
```

My Custom Repository:

```
public interface CustomMessageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Message,Long>{

      @Query(value = **MyStringSql**)
      public Page<Message> find(Pageable page);
}
```

I'm using JHipster + Spring Data. Using the examples I found, just can not run queries are passed parameter as fieldName and sort.

What is the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/

Comment: Another one that it is just like what you need: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-the-query-annotation/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it doesn't have a way to pass the table column value in the query :(

Comment: Can you clarify?! Essentially what you are asking is how to use a prepared statement with @query annotation and the links I provided do exactly that. What You didn't get or what you didn't explain in your question?

Comment: The problem is how to pass parameter for the column I want to filter the results dynamically.

Comment: Then you should consider in Using `Criteria` see it here: http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Yes the Criteria API is the way to go.